# Как создать server application на собственном компьютере принимающие соединения из вне?

Tags: сервер, сокет, порты, провайдер

На компьютере установлен Windows 10.
Можно сделать так, чтобы server appliaction написанный на java мог принимать запросы из вне, с помощью внешнего IP?
Я открыл соответствующий порт из настроек firewall, но сайты показывают, что соответствующий порт то ли filtered то ли closed.
При этом в `netstat -a` порт показан а в `netstat` нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще провайдер сказал, что в моем случае порты нельзя изменить так как у меня WIFI (у них тут firewall наверное) и что это возможно только при фиксированном соединении через кабель.

Выходит я со всеми могу связываться а сам слушать и принимать соединение не могу?
Спасибо.

EDIT:
У меня соединение осуществляется с помощью SIM карты, который я могу поставить или в WIFI или в телефон, нет никаких кабелей.

Я сделал следующее в настройках WIFI

Отключил firewall
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил виртуальный сервер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот мой настройка NAT
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но порт 5423 снова то ли filtered то ли closed.
И еще java application запущен на 0.0.0.0:5423

Comment: А от провайдера в квартиру кабель заходит ? Тогда вам надо: 1. убедиться что у вас реальный ip (уточнить у провайдера). 2. пробросить порт в настройках вашего WiFi роутера

Comment: @Mike у меня  в квартиру кабель не заходит смотрите выше раздел EDIT

Comment: Тогда остается верить тому, что вам сказала техподдержка провайдера. Вы видимо за NAT. Если NAT все таки на вашем роутере то попробуйте пробросить порты. Если у провайдера - то точно ничего не выйдет

Comment: @Mike Сделал некоторые вещи, но не помогло см. выше, но мне кажется NAT все таки на моем роутере.

Comment: На роутере пробросили верно, должно проходить. Но вот 127.0.0.1 никуда не годиться, он работает только внутри машины. приложение должно слушать на 0.0.0.0:5423. Правда ваше заявление про 127.0.0.1 противоречит первой картинке из netstat

Comment: @Mike Я в коде при создании сокета писал 127.0.0.1 но система везде показывает 0.0.0.0

Comment: хм. это странно. но попробуте в коде написать 0.0.0.0 и для начала соединиться в пределах домашней сети по адресу 192.168... убедить что так работет

Comment: @Mike программа-сервер работает на 0.0.0.0:5423 и соединение по адресу 192.168.1.100 прошел успешно.

Comment: И на роутере все верно. Значит остается NAT или фаервол у провайдера

Comment: Хотя стоп, у вас на роутере 192.168.1.101 указан а вы говорите что соединение с 100 прошло

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109054/discussion-between---and-mike).